# Validating certain parts of input string using Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

I am using `ASP.NET 4` and `Fluent Validation`.

I am trying to setup a rule that checks if my user name starts with "adm".

I have the following, giving me errors.  I tried to follow the online sample but it is not working:

```
RuleFor(x => x.UserName)
     .NotNull()
     .WithMessage("Required")
     .Must(x => x.UserName.StartsWith("adm"))
     .WithMessage("Must start with ADM");
```

I don't think I am doing it correctly?

I've event tried:

```
.Must(x => x.UserName.Substring(0, 3) == "adm")
```

Error for both:

```
Delegate 'System.Func<MyProject.ViewModels.LogOnViewModel,string,bool>' does not take 1 arguments
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `.Must(str => str.StartsWith("adm"))`

Answer (score 2):

```
RuleFor(f => f.UserName).NotNull();
RuleFor(f => f.UserName).Must((f, t) => f.UserName.StartsWith("adm")).WithMessage("Must start with ADM");
```

I solved this way.